# I cant install kali linux

Tags: linux, installation

I've downloaded a Kali Linux ISO and used Rufus to burn it to my 8 GB USB.

When I reboot my PC and it boots up from the USB this message pops up:

> invalid signature detected. check secure boot policy in setup

It reboots again and says "there's no boot device".

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does the computer currently have Windows installed?

Comment: no, linux ubuntu but the same thing happens on my windows 10 pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into UEFI Firmware Settings and disable Secure Boot.

1. Go into a terminal and run `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`. The system will reboot into UEFI Firmware Settings
2. Find the secure boot option (usually under `boot` or something like that)
3. Disable it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should disable secure boot in the BIOS.